# Passing String Parameters with C++ and Assembly x64

Tags: c++, assembly, 64-bit

i have this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
extern "C" char * DDD(char * h, int j);

int main()
{
char * g = "RRRR";
cout << "HELLO Says " << DDD(g, strlen(g)) << endl;
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

and this

```
.data
gh db 'Y'
.code
DDD proc
lea rbx, [rcx]
push rbx
a20:
mov al, gh
mov byte ptr [rbx], al
inc rbx
dec rdx
cmp rdx, 0
jnz a20
pop rbx
mov rax, rbx
ret
DDD endp
end
```

what im doing is to replace RRRR to become YYYY. i get errors at

```
mov byte ptr [rbx], al
```

it says access violation.

im new to assembly and i just want to know how to solve it. correction of assembly code is appreciated too.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The "RRRR" string is stored in read-only memory. You should replace its declaration by something like `char g[] = "RRRR";` to be able to write to it.

Comment: That's a good thing. Please consider accepting the answer if it fitted your need!